# Digital Isolation comparison

Tags: usb, digital-logic, isolation

I am currently using [ADuM4160 by Analog Devices](http://www.analog.com/en/interface-isolation/digital-isolators/adum4160/products/product.html) as a USB isolator.

However, this part is EXPENSIVE. I was wondering if anyone thinks it can be replaced with [ADuM2200](http://www.analog.com/en/interface-isolation/digital-isolators/adum2200/products/product.html).

Any reason why this wouldn't work? If so, any thing that needs to be done to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely not.

The ADuM4160 is expensive because it has **five** internal isolation channels. USB is a complex bus, as it's both bi-directional and differential. It's not easy or simple to isolate.

Also, the isolator needs to be fairly fast, USB-2.0 full-speed has a 12 Mbps signaling rate. Looking at a similar-speed 4-channel ADuM isolator, the costs are about the same.

Basically, there is no way to easily reduce the cost. Within the ADuM product line, the ADuM4160 is price-competitive with other devices of similar complexity.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Another way to save money would be to use a device with a lower insulation rating. Depending on your insulation rating needs (2.5kV vs 5kV) you might also consider the less expensive [ADuM3160](http://www.analog.com/en/interface-isolation/usb-isolators/products/index.html) as well. It is actually the same part, but will only isolate to half of the voltage.

Answer (score 3):

Doubt it.  USB is a bidirectional bus that uses differential signals, and the ADuM220 is a one-way isolator that uses ground-referenced logic.  Isolating bidirectional buses is more difficult than one-way buses.

I'm not sure, but I think if you build a device using the ADuM4160, it might comply to the USB standard, but if you jury-rig something out of combined one-way isolators, it wouldn't be likely to.